# MySQL connection to Python in Spyder IDE says module not found?

Tags: python, mysql, spyder

So I'm trying to connect Python and MySQL in Spyder IDE to complete my school project, the error its giving me is:

```
File "C:\Users\aakar\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py", line 356, in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File "c:\users\aakar\.spyder-py3\databaseintegrationpractice\test1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import mysql.connector as sqlcon

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql'
```

I tried to use a youtube tutorial and my textbook too but everything gives me this error, I have it installed using pip.
On running `pip3 install mysql-connector` I get:

```
Requirement already satisfied: mysql-connector in c:\users\aakar\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (2.2.9)
```

Comment: It works perfectly fine in Visual Studio Code only an error in spyder ide for some reason and I need to use Spyder IDE for the project or it won't be accepted.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please read [our instructions](http://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html#using-existing-environment) to learn how to connect Spyder to an external environment.

Answer (score 0):

Verify if you are installing packages in same environment you are using to run script. `mysql-connector` is a bit older, deprecated, and replaced by `mysql-connector-python`. If you want to stick with same, try downgrading your python version. I'm using it with python 3.8.8 and it is working fine.

Comment: What do I import it as?

Comment: It still says the same

Comment: This didn't work but thanks for trying to help!